# Switching between GCC and Clang when using the Gradle Experimental NDK plug-in in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, gradle-experimental

When using the Gradle Experimental NDK plug-in in Android Studio, how do you configure the Gradle build settings to build using Clang vs GCC (which has been deprecated)?

Comment: `model { android { ndk { toolchain "clang" } } }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to specify

`toolchain = 'gcc'`

in the **model.android.ndk** block in your build.gradle?

You can see the toolchains here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/nativeplatform/toolchain/package-summary.html

Comment: Ah, that might be it. Will try when I get back to this problem. Thanks for the link!